# Advice on which database to use for an image recognition iOS app

Tags: database, ios, iphone-app, sql, swift

I am looking for recommendations and advice on which database to use for an app I am developing.

I have the image recognition part of the app completed, however what I want to do now is query a database using the classification of the image and display the data found on that line in a table in the app. I know there are apps out there that do this but I can't find any documentation about how to do it.

I was of the mind that an SQL database would be best for me as it's an easy tabular form and I can input all the data manually as there is no need in the app for user input, it is purely informational. I understand that I'd need to write separate web services for this but I don't mind that, however if anyone has any suggestions about a better solution I'd love to hear/read about it!

Thank you!